# tbody и display: flex в IE

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица, которая прекрасно отображается во всех браузерах кроме IE разных версий. Выяснил, что в нем `tbody` не реагирует на `display: flex;`. Можно ли, как-то, побороть это поведение не переписывая таблицу на дивах?

Comment: `tbody` и  `display: flex;`  ты что пытаешься сделать?

Comment: В топку осла. В нем еще кто-то сидит? По моему, его используют, только для скачивания нормального браузера =))

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите по поводу префиксов тут http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox, но имейте введу dispay flex работает в IE очень забаговано